# Fetch data from sqlite3 and save in list

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to fetch data from a sqlite3 database and save them in a list.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("words.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT word FROM words WHERE state='positive'")
rows=cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print(rows)
```

The output of rows is this:

> [('abound',), ('abounds',), ('abundance',)]

I would like to have:

> ['abound', 'abounds', 'abundance']

I created the db with this:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, meta TEXT)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the first column of each returned row tuple.

```
rows = [r[0] for r in cur]
```

You don't need to commit after a select either.